# Wrong indentation and spacing for manual pages in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, documentation, command-line

I am wondering why the manual pages in the Terminal app look like shite on my Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.5?

If I run the command `man grep` for instance I get a crappy layout of text in the terminal window (black terminal). But if I right-click `grep` and choose *open man page* then I get the properly formatted version (yellow terminal) of the manual.

[image: See image below:]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-clicking a command and choosing *open man page* in the Terminal window uses the "Man Page" profile in the new Terminal window. In your current white-on-black profile you've set bolded text to black instead of white or another color. Therefore the bold text isn't visible on the black background.

Choosing yellow instead of black as color for bolded text in the Man Page theme would result in a similar crappy display of the grep man page:

[image]